# Is there a simple way that does not involve adding more end to end wires to make this a two way switching?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Below it is the wireing diagram that shows you how my garage lights are powered.
I intend to add the power outlet and the switch that are to the right of that brown dotted line, **they are not there yet, just the lights are there** The garage door lights are already there. The receptacle will have a ground wire, I missed to add that.

The initial idea was to be able to use the receptacle without having the lights on in the middle of the day.

After thinking more about it, I would like to be able to switch the entire circuit on either from the garage or from inside. Is this possible without adding more wiring? (I am ok to add any wires to the right of the dotted line) If yes, how?

[image]

Edit: the alternative that I have right now is to use home automation and switch the circuit on using my cell :-) That implies adding a 20-40CAD circuit in that box where the indoor switch is

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, smart switches are the way to do that.   I still don't understand why you want a switch on the PIR, however; it only disrupts its functionality.

So I would straight-wire right through the leftmost switch so it is bypassed.  In the right switch box, put a smart-switch "master" and control the garage lights.  Then in the leftmost switch box, fit a smart-switch "remote" that controls the master in a 2-way configuration (note that this switch does not interrupt any wires, but *taps* hot and neutral).

- Use systems like Insteon that use powerline signaling or their own radio comms (Insteon uses both), and therefore don't fail if you change your WiFi password.  Though it is certainly OK if they *also* talk WiFi/phone etc.

You have to be careful controlling lights with your phone.  Code requires *certain* lights to be controllable via a physical switch in the usual/expected locations; this is so guests can navigate your house, and "guests" includes first responders.  **Fortunately these aren't any of those locations, so you don't care about that**.   However, the second impact is to resale value.  Nobody wants to buy a house where they can't control the lights.  And the smart-aleck response of "install an app" is going to cost you $1000 on their offer, because they will assume you did this a lot, and they'll have to put $1000 into an electrician to make it all normal again.

Comment: The buyer will not see it because I can remove it. Taking it with me to the next house. No I don't want to use smart switches for now... just simple wiring tricks if possible. I up voted your response as that opened my eyes in regards to code implications for smart switches and visitors. I never thought about it (in the process of automating my house)

Comment: a switch is needed for changing the mode of the PIR,  flick twice to stay on  etc...